# Azure VM Merge Data Disks

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine

I have a data processing VM in Azure with some existing data disks. Now, i would like to create a new volume (F:/) with 8TB capacity using two 4TB data disks. I am not sure how to do this by merging two different disks and making it one volume. Do someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure how to do this by merging two different disks and
>   making it one volume

It seems you are using windows server.

You can use windows storage pools, in this way, you can merge two disks as one volume.

More information about storage pools, please refer to this [blog](https://nedimmehic.org/2017/05/01/how-to-configure-storage-spaces-and-tiered-storage-windows-server-2016/).

Comment: Does this work for you? please let me know if you need more help:)